# What is the scope of error_get_last() in PHP?

Tags: php

I've been using `error_get_last()` in combination with `register_shutdown_function()` to create an error report for some of my scripts. It's been working fine for the most part.
Every now and then, though, the error report will show an error from a different script.

I'm not quite sure how that can happen. Can anyone explain?
I'm wondering if `error_get_last()` in one script should be able to show errors from different scripts and if that's the case, under what circumstances would that happen?
My only guess is that the error is saved for a short time so that a script that finishes execution at almost the same time might catch another script's errors. Could that be it?

This is the code I use and have included in many different PHP files:

```
function send_error_report($extra) {
        global $conn;
        $base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url = $base_url . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        
        $error = error_get_last();
        
        if (isset($error)) {
            $error_str = "Type: " . $error['type'] . " | Message: " . $error['message'] . " | File: " . $error['file'] . " | Line: " . $error['line'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `error_report` (`script`, `error`) VALUES ('$url', '" . $error_str . " - " . $extra . "');";
            
            $conn->query($sql);
        }
    }
    register_shutdown_function('send_error_report', '');
```

Comment: It's global state, all the more reason to avoid it. Use an exception, which can carry relevant error info. Apart from other advantages, it captures the error infos where and when it happens. That said, your question is unclear. You suspect various other scripts to influence each other, but how could anyone guess how without a [mcve] and info about the whole execution environment.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the info. Your first statement "It's global state" really answers the question for me. That's the reason. I guess the errors are cleared pretty quickly, as I am not able to get an error when I try at a random point in time